# HTML5 app canvas fullscreen on Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, html, mobile-safari

I'm developing a HTML5 app based on canvas.
I go to full screen, address bar and menu bar (navigation bar, button bar, whatever you call the bar on bottom) are hidden.

BUT, when I click on the place where navigation bar or address bar used to be, they reappear again.

It happens on iPhone 5c with iOS 10 installed.

(Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14A456 Safari/602.1)

Is it possible to prevent these bar from reappearing except in case when scrolled down?

Comment: It is default behavior, otherwise it will never appear again :P

Comment: It doesn't happen on iPhone 6, but it does on 5c